# Compiler Error: no match for 'operator[]' C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, g++

The compiler says the following error message for my simple depth first search algorithm written in C++:

> error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'std::vector' and 'std::vectorstd::vector<int >::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iteratorstd::vector<int*, std::vectorstd::vector<int > >}')
> if (!visited[i])

Here is the code block:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
...
vector<bool> visited;
vector<vector<int>> adj_matrix;
...
void dfs(int n) {
  //Possible problem
  if (!visited[n])
    visited[n] = true;
  for (vector<int> row : adj_matrix) {
    for (vector<vector<int>>::iterator i = adj_matrix.begin();
         i != adj_matrix.end(); ++i) {
      if (!visited[i])
        dfs(row[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried using a pointer as an array index, like so:

```
    if (!visited[*n])
    visited[*n] = true;
```

but it says the exact same thing.

Comment: What you identify as the "problem area" is wrong. The problem is your usages of the iterator **`i`** as index.

Comment: Additionally: be wary of [vector<bool>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool)

Comment: On a couple of unrelated notes, please [don't include `<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) or [use `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Those are bad habits.

Comment: While it is not the main issue, note that `for (vector<int> row : adj_matrix)` will make a _copy_ of each row, which is wasteful. Consider using a reference-to-const instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `visited[i]`, where `i` is an iterator. If you want to iterate two vectors with a common index, then use directly a `int` or `size_t`, because iterators belong to a single container (in this case, to `adj_matrix`, not to `visited`) and behave like pointers, not like indexes.

So replace your last piece of code with this:

```
for (vector<int> row : adj_matrix) {
    for (int i = 0; i != adj_matrix.size(); ++i) {
      if (!visited[i])
        dfs(row[i]);
    }
}
```